# Node.js fs.writeFileSync with options and callback and error hundler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I looked at [Node.js Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) and I didn't find how to apply options (settings) and a callback function with error handling. And I have to use .writeFileSync (not asynchronous .writeFile):

```
const settings = {
        flags: 'w',
        encoding: null, //must be null
        mode: 0o666,
        autoClose: true //not found this option
      };

fs.writeFileSync(dest, buff, settings);
```

Before I used:

```
fs.writeFileSync(dest, buff, function (err) {
  if (err) { 
    ... 
  } else { ... console.log("OK") }

})
```

but I found that I have to apply **encoding: null,** option to prevent any modifications of source data (buff), in other case the file can be broken.

Edit:
After amazing answers and explanations I would like to say that I was confused with Node.js Documentation :
**fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])** is

> **The synchronous version of fs.writeFile().**

Since this is version of fs,writeFile() method I thought it can have the same versions of function's signature...

And here my final version of code, but **it still has the issue with decoding  of binary files (can be any file types)** (* by the way when I tried to use Axios.js I saw Errors: "Request failed with Status Code 500):
[image]

```
function download(url, dest, fileName, callback) {

  //import http from 'http';
  var request = http.get(url, function (response) {

    var bodyParts = [];
    var bytes = 0;

    response.on("data", function (c) {
      bodyParts.push(c);
      bytes += c.length;
    })

    response.on("end", function () {

      // flatten into one big buffer
      var buff = new Buffer(bytes);
      var copied = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < bodyParts.length; i++) {
        bodyParts[i].copy(buff, copied, 0);
        copied += bodyParts[i].length;
      }

      const settings = {
        flags: 'w',
        encoding: null, //not applicable / no changes
        mode: 0o666
      };

      try {
        fs.writeFileSync(dest, buff, settings);

        let msgOK = {
          filename: fileName,
          status: 'OK',
          text: `File downloaded successfully`
        }
        if (callback) callback(msgOK);
        console.log(msgOK.text);
        isLoading = false; //IMPORTANT! 

      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.stack || err.message);

        let msgErr = {
          filename: fileName,
          status: 'ERROR',
          text: `Error in file downloading ${err.message}`
        }
        ERRORS.push(err);
        if (callback) callback(msgErr);
      }

    })

  })

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **synchronous** version of any file system method does not accept a callback and they will throw in case of error, so you should catch it.

> When using the synchronous form any exceptions are immediately thrown.
>   You can use try/catch to handle exceptions or allow them to bubble up.

```
try {
    fs.writeFileSync(dest, buff);
    // You don't need callback, the file is saved here
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

There's no setting `autoClose` for `fs.writeFileSync` the only available options are:

```
encoding <String> | <Null> default = 'utf8'
mode <Number> default = 0o666
flag <String> default = 'w'
```

Last but not least, you should update your node version, since Node.js 4.x [end of life](https://github.com/nodejs/Release) is in less than a week. (2018-04-30)

Comment: I have an idea: If fs.writeFileSync is a synchronous  version of fs.writeFile does it mean I can use:
  //fs.writeFileSync(dest, buff, settings);
  //fs.writeFile(file, data, encoding, callback);
  //fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback);

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. Previously you said you have to use the sync version, why is that?

Comment: I understood. You answered already: there is no synchronous method with callback :(

Comment: but why you want a callback if it sync?

Comment: only for sending confirmation of successful task completion after saving a file on the drive.

Comment: Check the comment in my code, you don't need a callback, the line after `fs.writeFileSync` is enough confirmation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169810/discussion-between-marcos-casagrande-and-alex-pilugin).

Answer (score 1):

`fs.writeFileSync` throws an error
so you can do

```
try {
  fs.writeFileSync(dest, buff)
} catch (err) {
  // do something
}
```

and you wouldn't need callback because it's synchronous
just put your code after calling `writeFileSync`

Comment: Thank you. I understood finally why I don't need a callback

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you can use

```
try {
  fs.writeFileSync(dest, buff, settings);
} catch(e) {
  // do your error handler
}
```